# I can't find where Shulchan Aruch is in Tur v'Shulcahn Aruch HaBahir

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, shulchan-aruch, tur

Through this site, I knew that there are the Seforim including Tur and Shulchan Aruch, so I am considering purchasing them.

But I'm not sure if Shulchan Aruch is in the book just by looking at the [**look inside**](https://seforimcenter.com/showScannedImages.aspx?pfile=8956.gif), but rather, it's only showing Tur and the commentary about the sefer.

I want to know whether there is Shulchan Aruch in Tur v'Shulcahn Aruch HaBahir

Comment: Asking a store trying to sell you something is probably more effective than asking us

Comment: Sites selling seforim typically only show a few preview pages from the front of the book, so if the arrangement in this set is that the Tur is in the front and SA is in the back, you wouldn't see the SA in the preview... if you are concerned about whether the advertised content is actually in the book your best bet is to pick up the phone and discuss it with the merchant (who has presumably held or could hold the product in his hand).

Comment: assuming it is this set, I have a few volumes and it is Tur and Shulchan Aruch together: https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/tur-v-shulchan-aruch-habahir-38-volume-set-684233.html

Comment: I usually recommend finding a physical copy of the sefer you want to see if you like it before purchase. If you have a local kollel, see if they have a set.

Comment: In the set you've described, as well as in other publications of Tur and Shulchan Aruch Together (like שלחן מלכים), they way it is arranged is that the Tur appears first and the Shulchan Aruch is after it. Some publishers may have some sort of ליקוט of meforshim on the Tur which would appear after the Tur and before the Shulchan Aruch.